# Using C#/VB.NET values in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have searched for a definitive answer to my question and not been able to find one.  Lots a site cover the topic but I cannot find the answer I am looking for.

I have an ASPX page that, for example, processes customer queries.  In the code behind I have a Customer class. If I want to use, for example, the customer ID and Name in a JavaScript function.  What is the best way for me to do it?

I have this code (a website I have been asked to update) but I try to sort out all warnings VS displays and this code displays two.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoSomeThingFunction(enable)
{
    var enableStr = enable ? "on" : "off";
    var intClientID = <%= Customer.ClientID %>;
    var strClientName = <%= Customer.ClientName %>;

    <!--
        More functionality
    -->

};
</script>
```

Expected expression on the following two lines..

```
var intClientID = <%= Customer.ClientID %>;
var strClientName = <%= Customer.ClientName %>;
```

I can update this code to stop the warnings..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DoSomeThingFunction(enable)
{
    var enableStr = enable ? "on" : "off";
    var intClientID = parseInt('<%= Customer.ClientID %>');
    var strClientName = '<%= Customer.ClientName %>';

    <!--
        More functionality
    -->

};
</script>
```

My question is:  What is the best method of achieving this without getting any kind of warning?  Does the best method mean I will get a warning and therefore have to put up with it?  I hate to see warnings of any kind and try to fix them all.

Thanks for looking

Comment: Warnings can be annoying, but as long as the generated markup is valid, it really doesn't matter. However, I use code very similar to yours to avoid the warnings.

Comment: Your `strClientName` needs the string designation anyway, but you're pretty much stuck with the warning for the integer.  The only other option (which may cause readability to suffer) would be to define some of those variables (assuming they're global to the page) in a registered script from the code-behind.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  I guess there are many ways to achieve this without getting warnings and maybe I do get too hung up on VS warnings.  Its difficult to decide which to mark as an answer as they all add to the overall answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first code block is how I have done it in the past. If the value is a string single or double quoted. Numbers are ok to not have quotes.

Another approach is to use hidden fields in the page.

```
<input type="hidden" id="customerId" value="1234" />
<input type="hidden" id="customerName" value="John Doe" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function DoSomeThingFunction(enable)
{
    var enableStr = enable ? "on" : "off";
    var intClientID = $('input#customerId').val(); //using jQuery to retrieve the value
    var strClientName = $('input#customerName').val();

    <!--
        More functionality
    -->

};
</script>
```

I don't worry about VS warnings, in fact I rarely look at them. Most of the time the code will still work as expected and especially when it comes to html, css and javascript the warnings are obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following from code (in pre render for example) to register the variables:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "variables", 
  String.Format("var intClientID = {0};var strClientName = '{1}';", 
     Customer.ClientID, 
     Customer.ClientName), 
   true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know ClientID is an integer and ClientName is a string, the second block of code you have is much better.  I'm thinking the JS validator in VS sees the assignments and since it can't confirm that <%=...%> is number data type, it wants to see quotes around it.  In addition, if ClientName was in fact a string, your JS would fail at runtime anyways as the string would *need* to be surrounded in quotes.